# Running Secondary Threads in Background Continuosly

Tags: objective-c

I need to create a new thread which will have infinite while loop, so that it won't block main UI thread. The newly created thread is getting killed when I send the application to background mode, But I need to run it in background. Any help?

Comment: Background tasks must be executed using grand central dispatch, and have a time limit of 10 minutes. I suggest you search for iOS background tasks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between a Background Thread and a Background Task in iOS, but the underlying answer remains the same;  don't run a background thread unless you simply cannot avoid it.   Furthermore, you can't just spin off a thread and have it run if your app wants to support backgrounding in iOS.

First, you should [read the documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)   It is extensive and provides many examples.

Then, if you have any specific questions not covered by the docs (or to clarify the docs), ask 'em here!